# How do I prevent Visio from being prefixed when printing PDFs?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I use Visio 2013 often for corporate usage and whenever I print using the Adobe Acrobat printer, it always adds a `Visio_filename.pdf prefix`. No other program does this. While it is a nuisance I can deal with, I prefer not to deal with it any longer.  Any help in remedying this is greatly appreciated.

I should mentioned that I use the Print option to PDF Printer rather than using the Office built in Exporter.

Comment: I use Visio 2013 and I don't have such a problem

Comment: Hmm, guess I will pony up for the upgrade... I am a decade behind the times I suppose then!

Comment: I just bought Visio 2013 and I still have the same problem.  Hmm.

Comment: When I make a diagram in Visio 2013 and name it `Diagram.vsdx` and then click export to PDF, Visio 2013 automatically names it `Diagram.pdf`. There is no prefix added in my case.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour with Visio 2010 and Acrobat 10. It seems to not do it with Create PDF button if that's an option.

Comment: I should had mentioned I use the Print option to PDF Printer rather than using the Office built in Exporter.

Comment: @JonWeinraub So using the Office built in PDF Exporter, does it solve your problem ? There is a even faster way to create a pdf document from a Office 2013 document. If you are interested I will post it as answer.

Comment: It does for the prefix issue. However quality is subpar to adobe acrobat. So I guess I'll live with erasing it.